# Length of an HTMLObjectCollection is incorrect in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript

I have three cells in different rows in a table having same name.e.g.

```
<td name = "x">
```

is present in 3 different rows.

I am using document.getElementsByName() to obtain a collection of these cells and trying to calculate the length of this collection. e.g.

```
var obj = doucment.getElementsByName("X");
  var length = obj.length;
```

This code works fine in Google Chrome but in IE the length is return as 0(zero).

Can anyone tell me how to sove this problem in IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think name is a valid attribute for TD elements, it should be used for Form elements.

Use class instead.

```
<td class="whatever">
```

And:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("whatever").length
```

If you need to use multiple classes, this supported as well:

```
<td class="whatever whatever2 allwhatevers">
```

Comment: I am already using a class with these three <td>s and same class is used at other places also.

Comment: +1 its valid for Forms/form elements, images, anchors etc but not TD

Comment: Note that `getElementsByClassName()` is not supported in IE8 and below: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t11. You can use `document.querySelectorAll('.whatever')` to support IE8 (but not IE7), or use a polyfill.